# When I use a value from a dictionary instead of coming out as a flat 65 it comes out as a scientific notation. How do I prevent this?

Tags: python-2.7

I am making a text based game experiment thing for fun because I just started learning about a week ago, when I use the value of health that the player has instead of 65 it comes up as 6.500000e+01 which, doesn't read very well how do I prevent this?  This is my first time here should I post my whole code?

```
if 'eat' in food:

    print "Then starts the feast, you eat everything you can reach.  After a while you become to tired and need to rest."
    print "You wake up with no sense of how much time has passed. You ate too much but feel healthier. You continue on into through the only doors you can see."
    player["health"] += 15
    print "You are now at %(health) health." % player
```

Comment: This usually happens when the value is a floating point number, and its value is not precise, maybe it is 65.0000000000000001, and Python rounds it to 6.50000e+01. What else are you doing with that value?

Comment: Do `print(type(player['health']))` at the start of that block of code. If it's `float`, that's because the original value stored in the dictionary was a `float`, and adding a `float` and an `int` gives you an int.

Answer (score 1):

"Try %d" % (player ["health"])